# cannot adapt type when using custom field in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to add custom field to the actor admin panel to show the movie counts each contributed in
admin panel..

```
from django.contrib import admin

from actors.models import Actor


@admin.register(Actor)
class ActorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('actor_name',)
    list_filter = ('gender',)
    list_display = ['actor_name', 'age', 'gender', 'movies_count']
    readonly_fields = ['movies_count']

    def movies_count(self, obj):
        count = 0
        for mv in Actor.objects.raw('select * from movies_movie_actors '
                                    'where actor_id='
                                    '(select id from actors_actor where actor_name="%s")', [obj]):
            count += 1
        return str(count)

    movies_count.short_description = 'movie count'
```

but I get error

- Exception Type:  ProgrammingError
- Exception Value: can't adapt type 'Actor'

**what does the error mean, why is it show and how to solve it (different approach with the same goal is acceptable)**

*maybe relevant*

actor model :

```
from django.db import models

GENDER_LIST = [('male', 'male'), ('female', 'female')]


class Actor(models.Model):
    actor_name = models.fields.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=25, unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(verbose_name='Gender', choices=GENDER_LIST, max_length=6, default='male')
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    create_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Created at', auto_now=True)
    update_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Updated at', auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.actor_name}'
```

movies model :

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CASCADE

from director.models import Director


class Movie(models.Model):
    movie_name = models.fields.CharField(verbose_name='movie name', max_length=25, unique=True)
    production_year = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='production year')
    actors = models.ManyToManyField('actors.actor')
    director = models.ForeignKey(Director, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='movies')
    create_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Created at', auto_now=True)
    update_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Updated at', auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.movie_name}'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.director.director_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to reach the same goal (get movie count for each actor he/she contributed at) by using count() built in function with __set

```
def movies_count(self, obj):
   return obj.movie_set.count()
```

but the question still rise what does **can't adapt type** exception means?! and why it happens with the raw query?!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try not to ask another question in your answer. Instead [edit] the original question to reflect that or ask a new question.